# NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath returns false instead of true

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

How is it possible?

```
let exists = NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(path.absoluteString)
print("exists: \(exists)") //false
```

This is `path.absoluteString`

```
//file:///Users/kuna/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/92BD140D-5C14-43C4-80D6-904BB9594ED6/data/Containers/Data/Application/5B818832-BB19-4047-A7F8-1487F36868D6/Documents/wishlists/68/147/128/IMG_0006.PNG
```

And you can see it is there where it should be:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: can you print the document directory func printDocument() {
        let pathToFile = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSSearchPathDirectory.CachesDirectory , .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
        do {
            let namesOfFile = try Manager.contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(pathToFile)
            for name in namesOfFile {
                    print("name : \(name)")
            }
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print("print : \(error)")
        }
    }

Comment: so apparently the file does not exist . How do you Save it

Answer (score 141, accepted):

*(The code in this answer has been updated for Swift 3 and later.)*

Apparently your `path` variable is a `NSURL` (describing a file path). To get the path as
a string, use the `path` property, not `absoluteString`:

```
let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path.path)
```

`absoluteString` returns the URL in a string format, including
the `file:` scheme etc.

Example:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/path/to/foo.txt")

// This is what you did:
print(url.absoluteString)
// Output:    file:///path/to/foo.txt

// This is what you want:
print(url.path)
// Output:    /path/to/foo.txt
```

Comment: It worked, what is the difference since it is completely the same when I print it?

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk the difference is absoluteString also includes `file://` like this: `file:///Users/kuna/...`, path just returns `/Users/kuna/...`

Answer (score 5):

If you want to check if a path exist,you should check path

```
let url = NSURL(string: "balabala")

let path = url?.path
//Check path
```

Comment: This is the right answer and you got +1 but you should be more clear.

if (FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: url?.path.path))

Answer (score 4):

`FileManager` extension that allows to check if file exists using `URL`, supports changes in `iOS 16`:

```
import Foundation

extension FileManager {
    func fileExists(atURL url: URL) -> Bool {
        var path: String
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            path = url.path(percentEncoded: false)
        } else {
            path = url.path
        }

        return FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: path)
    }
}
```

How to use:

```
let exists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atURL: url)
```

Comment: Your answer saves my time! Than you!

Comment: thank you, I was missing the percentEncoded: false part, makes a lot of sense!