# Cannot convert value of type '()?' to specified type Bool

Tags: swift

I try to write code which changes property of file, but I get a compiler error.

Here is the code:

```
func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL(URL: NSURL) -> Bool{

    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    assert(fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(URL.absoluteString))

    var error:NSError?
    let success:Bool = try? URL.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

    if !success {
        print("Error excluding \(URL.lastPathComponent) from backup \(error)")
    } else {
        print("File at path \(URL) was succesfully updated")
    }

    return success
}
```

and the error is:

> Cannot convert value of type '()?' to specified type 'Bool'

How can I fix it?

Comment: Note that `URL.absoluteString` most probably should be `URL.path`, compare for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135305/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-fileexistsatpath-returns-false-instead-of-true.

Answer (score 2):

Call to `url?.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true),forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)` doesn't return a `Bool`. You are expecting a `Bool` as response. Thats the reason for error.

Apple documentation for `setResourceValue` method says

> In Swift, this method returns `Void` and is marked with the `throws`
>   keyword to indicate that it throws an error in cases of failure.

```
do {
    try url?.setResourceValue(NSNumber(bool: true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)

    //...
}
catch let error as NSError {
     //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I achieve this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1719/_index.html then ?