# Swift Error: cannot convert of type '()' to specified type 'Bool'

Tags: swift

I am New for Swift and I Have Implement File Manager Concept in my Project but it shows the issue and I don't for how to solve this please any body help me for fix the issue.

Here I Post My Code.

```
class func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath(filePathString: String) throws -> Bool
{
    let URL: NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePathString)
    assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(URL.path!))
    let err: NSError? = nil

    let success: Bool = try URL.setResourceValue(Int(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) //---- This Line Shows the Issue.

    if !success {
        NSLog("Error excluding %@ from backup %@", URL.lastPathComponent!, err!)
    }
    return success
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210898/cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-specified-type-bool

Comment: @Saravana -in place 
 let success: Bool = try URL.setResourceValue(Int(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) 
write
 let success: Bool = try URL?.setResourceValue(Int(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) 
or
 let success: Bool = try? URL.setResourceValue(Int(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey) 
give us your feedback.

Comment: Thanks for your help @DEVENDRAAGNIHOTRI

Comment: is this answer worked for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The benefit of the new error handling in Swift 2 is the omission of the quasi-redundant return values `Bool` / `NSError`. Therefore `setResourceValue` does not return a `Bool` anymore which is the reason of the error message.

As the function is marked as `throws` I recommend this syntax which just passes the result of `setResourceValue`

```
class func addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath(filePathString: String) throws
{
    let url = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(filePathString)
    assert(NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(URL.path!))

    try url.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
}
```

Handle the error in the method which calls `addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtPath`

Comment: Thanks for you help..@vadian

Answer (score 1):

The method `setResourceValue` is a throw function and does not return a Bool.

Try running your function using a do-catch:

```
do {
    try URL.setResourceValue(Int(true), forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey)
}
catch {
    NSLog("Error excluding %@ from backup %@", URL.lastPathComponent!, err!)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.@Julian Lee