# Swift error: Cannot convert value of type '() throws -> ()' to specified type 'Bool'

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-swift-bridge

I have a function in Objective C that returns a `BOOL` and has a single `errorOut` parameter. The swift bridge converts the `errorOut` parameter into a `throws` as expected but it also stops the `BOOL` being returned.

I can see that usually the `BOOL` is returned to indicate success/error but in this case the bool is actually wanted. What changes would I need to make to make sure the bool gets returned?

Objective C function signature

```
- (BOOL)hasAnyData:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorOut;
```

Comment: Not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45565960/ns-refined-for-swift-and-return-value as although the answer leads you to the right solution the question is different.

Also, definitely not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35810651/swift-error-cannot-convert-of-type-to-specified-type-bool

Comment: That is what is meant by a duplicate.  That he answers are the same.  Not that the question is identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MartinR for linking to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566261/238166) where I found this trick:

Changing the Objective C function declaration to

```
- (BOOL)hasAnyData:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorOut __attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)));
```

And then calling it from Swift like

```
let hasAnyData: Bool = try self.repo.hasAnyThings()
```

Does exactly what I wanted!

The `swift_error` attribute is documented here: https://github.com/apple/swift-clang/blob/383859a9c4b964af3d127b5cc8abd0a8f11dd164/include/clang/Basic/AttrDocs.td#L1800-L1819

---

Original answer - doesn't fully solve the problem but may be useful to someone else looking at this question as it is useful in a similar situation.

I finally found this in the Swift docs:

> Use the `NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW` macro on an Objective-C method declaration
>   that produces an NSError to prevent it from being imported by Swift as
>   a method that throws.

I have now added a `NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW` annotation to my Objective C function declaration like

```
- (BOOL)hasAnyData:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)errorOut NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW;
```

And am having to pass in the `NSError pointer` from Swift

```
var error: NSError?
let hasAnyData = self.repo.hasAnyData(&error)
```

This isn't the nicest because I can no longer handle the error in a swifty way (using `do, try catch` and instead have to use the `NSError`) but it's the best I could find.

Comment: `__attribute__((swift_error(nonnull_error)))` should be what you need, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/45566261/1187415.

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need - I'll test it and update my answer accordingly. Thanks @MartinR