# How to avoiding file:// in URL.absoluteString in swift4

Tags: swift

I have an application where I need to keep an index over files in a directory and I need to be able to access these files. However, when I have a `URL` object and call the `absoluteString` to get the path to either folder or a file it prepends the String with `file://`. First of I am not sure why it does this and secondly, how to avoid this, without utilising string manipulation.

/Lars

Comment: Use `.path`, not `.absoluteString`. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/q/34135305/1187415.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `path: String?` property of your URL instance

```
if url.isFileURL, let path = url.path {
    print(path)
} else {
    print("Not file URL")    
}
```