# Swift 4.0 - Unable to create empty text file in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager

Below is my code - 
I have tried to get the document directory path and with standard FileManager singleton tried to create a file, but I am not able to create the file, as the error -

> Unable to store data: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The file “CrashLog.txt” doesn’t exist."
>
> UserInfo={NSFilePath=file:///Users/ABC/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/87317777-63E7-422B-A55F-878E3267AFB8/data/Containers/Data/Application/4B41AA87-E4B9-4EE4-A67F-AC3B018913CC/Documents/CrashLog,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x600000244ec0 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain
>   Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

Code in development -

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
if (paths.count > 0) {
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let logFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("CrashLog.txt").absoluteString
    let _string = "Hello"
    //Create file at given path
    let data = _string.data(using: .utf8)
    //let attributes = FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: logFilePath)
    let fileExists : Bool = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFilePath)
    print(fileExists)
    let isFileCreated =  FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: logFilePath, contents: data, attributes: nil)
    print("ifFileCreated", isFileCreated)
}
```

Comment: Nvm, I didn't properly read your code. Whatever @Larme says!

Comment: `let logFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("CrashLog.txt")` instead, don't use the `absoluteString`, and so: `(atPath: logFilePath.path)` (twice) should do the trick.

Comment: Related: [NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath returns false instead of true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34135305/nsfilemanager-defaultmanager-fileexistsatpath-returns-false-instead-of-true)

Comment: I don't remember the exact answer for this, but bear in mind that `.absoluteString` and `.path` return different things, I remember having an issue that was caused by using absoluteString instead of path.

Answer (score 2):

The API `absoluteString` is wrong. The correct API is `path`

`absoluteString` returns the entire URL string representation including the scheme `file://`. On the other hand the `path` API of `FileManager` expects file system paths, the string **without** the scheme.

You are encouraged to use the URL related API anyway and you can write `Data` directly to disk without explicitly creating a file.

```
let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let logFileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("CrashLog.txt")
let string = "Hello"

let data = Data(string.utf8)

let fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFileURL.path)
print(fileExists)
do {
    try data.write(to: logFileURL)
    print("data written")
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: I used `absoluteString` everywhere and file creation always failed. Wasted a lot of time trying to figure out where the problem was in these simple five lines of code.... When I started using [path()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/3988473-path) (as of iOS 16.0), everything worked. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I ran your code on my iPhone, and it prints "true" and "data written", but I cannot find the CrashLog.txt file anywhere on my phone. I am looking in the Files app. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Here's my take on what you've done. Adopt the URL-based means of working with files. The best way to write data (for this example, at least), is to use Data's ability (not FileManager) to write to a file, again, using a URL. In most cases, you don't need to worry whether the file exists or not; just do it, and handle any error that arises.

```
    if var url = try? FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory,
                                              in: .userDomainMask,
                                              appropriateFor: nil,
                                              create: false) {
        url = url.appendingPathComponent("CrashLog").appendingPathExtension("txt")
        let _string = "Hello"
        if let data = _string.data(using: .utf8) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: url)
                print("successful")
            } catch {
                print("unsuccessful")
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The appendingPathComponent method if the receiver (e.g. parameter) does not end with a trailing slash, then it may read file metadata to determine whether the resulting path is a directory. That means it may produce the error you are seeing, so better use the appendingPathComponent(_:isDirectory:) instead.

For example:

```
let logFilePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).appendingPathComponent("CrashLog.txt", isDirectory: false).absoluteString
```